# solving differential equation using general solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Not sure if I have done this correctly

$$x\frac{dy}{dx} + (1+x)y=e^{-x}\sin(2x)$$
Divide the equation by x
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1+x}{x}y-\frac{e^{-x}\sin(2x)}{x}$$
and Integrating factor is
$$ e^{\int \frac{1+x}{x}dx} = e^{\int (x^{-1}+1)dx} = e^{\ln|x|+x}$$
multiply the equation with integrating factor, left side is the derivative or integrating factor and y
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\ln|x|+x}y)=\frac{e^{-x}e^{\ln|x|+x}\sin(2x)}{x}$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(e^{\ln|x|+x}y)=\sin(2x)$$ 
integrate both sides gets
$$e^{\ln|x|+x}y=\frac{-\cos(2x)}{2} + C$$ 
solution of explicit form
$$\rightarrow y=\frac{-\cos(2x)}{2e^{\ln|x|+x}} + C$$

Do I get all steps done correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct and all steps are perfect. Just change the $e^{\ln|x|+x}$ in the answer to $|x|e^x$. Rest is all right.

**P.S.** You can write $x$ in place of $|x|$ since in the 5th step from top, you have cancelled $|x|$ and $x$ meaning you have considered $x$ to be positive. In other words, the equation $$y=-\frac{\cos 2x}{2xe^x}+c$$ holds for all positive x only.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Aniket's answer

1. You forgot to divide the constant by your integrating factor. The solution should be

$$ y = -\frac{\cos 2x + C}{2xe^x} $$

2. If you follow the same steps for $x < 0$, you would still end up with this solution
   $$ \frac{d}{dx}(|x|e^x y) = \frac{|x|\sin 2x}{x} $$
   $$ \frac{d}{dx}(-xe^x y) = -\sin 2x $$
   $$ -xe^x y = \frac{\cos 2x + C}{2} $$
   $$ y = -\frac{\cos 2x + C}{2xe^x}$$